# On Lebesgue measure in 3 dimensional euclidean space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $E_{\alpha}=[(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=\alpha^2]$, $\alpha$ is irrational. Define $E=\bigcup E_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ varies over all irrationals, what is lebesgue measure of $E$, and what is the lebesgue measure of any open set containing $E^c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E^{c}$ has measure $0$ because it is a countable union of sets of measure $0$. This implies that measure of $E$ is $\infty $. The measure of an open set containing $E^{c}$ can be finite or infinity.

Comment: But I think any open set containing $E^c$ must be full set $R^3$ since the rational spheres it has to contain.

Comment: No. Arrange the rationals in a sequence $\{r_n\}$ and consider the union of the sets $\{(x,y,z):r_n-\epsilon_n < x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} <r_n+\epsilon_n$. This is an open set containing $E^{c}$ and its measure is finite; we can make this measure as small as we want by making $\epsilon_n$ 's small.